# Safari can't load a page with https

Tags: https, safari, interspire-shopping-cart

I have a shopping cart which is built in interspire. i have applied GeoTrust SSL for checkout and admin page.

When i load https pages in mozilla or chrome it works well. but when we load https pages in safari it gives me the following error: safari can't open page. We face this issue on both Mac and Windows

Address of our site link is https://www.4living.co.uk/admin/

Comment: Are you using an iframe on the page?

Comment: No i am using no iframe

Answer (score 0):

This may have to deal with the configuration or architecture of the browser. Check the browser help section on how to access a site with https on the browser.